# Discrepancy between 2 functions [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have 2 functions, in first I'am generation random number and setting probability. In second functions cheking the generated number is in certain range. And if its in certain range setting value to variable.

```
            function chance($input = array()) {
                $number  = rand(0, array_sum($input) * 10);
                $starter = 0;
                $b       = 3;
                foreach ($input as $key => $val) {
                    $starter += $val * 10;
                    if ($number <= $starter) {
                        $ret = $key;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                return $ret;
                //return $b;;
            }

            function in_range($number, $min, $max, $inclusive = FALSE) {
                if (is_int($number) && is_int($min) && is_int($max)) {
                    return $inclusive ? ($number >= $min && $number <= $max) : ($number > $min && $number < $max);
                }

                return FALSE;
            }

            $array = array(
                rand(0, 9885) => 81.9,
                rand(9886, 9985) => 15.1,
                rand(9986, 9993) => 1,
                rand(9994, 9997) => 0.09,
                rand(9998, 9999) => 0
            );
    $rolledNumber = chance($array);
                $coinsWon = 0;
if (in_range($rolledNumber, 0, 9885) == true) {
        $coinsWon = 5;
                } elseif (in_range($rolledNumber, 9886, 9985) == true) {
                    $coinsWon = 10;
                } elseif (in_range($rolledNumber, 9986, 9993) == true) {
                    $coinsWon = 50;
                }
```

After a few tests found that there are dismaches. For example:

Getting number 9884, and the value of coinswon is 10, but should be 5. Also I thing that the probability options its not working properly, because for 9986, 9993 numbers I've set 1% probability, but numbers in this range are generated frequently

Comment: When you say "numbers in this range are generated frequently", have you measured _how_ frequently? How many times did you run the code? We're talking about randomness, after all, so the proportions will only approach what you've set over a large number of runs. (Also, as written the expected frequency is not 1% but 1 in 98, since your chance function uses the sum of the values in the array as its base, not 100).

Comment: A simple test of the `chance` function would be a function like this: `function test($num_tries, $input) { for($i=0;$i<$num_tries;$i++) { $counters[ chance($input) ]++; } var_dump($counters); }`